# What would be a command to zip all folders in a directory

Tags: directory, zip

I have a few folders in a directory that I want to zip individually.

```
Root
    -folder1
    -folder2
```

into:

```
Root
    -folder1.zip
    -folder2.zip
    -folder1
    -folder2
```

What would be a command to achieve that?

Comment: Possibly `for I in folder?; do zip -r $I $I; done`?

Answer (score 1):

```
dir_name=$(find /root/* -maxdepth 0 -type d)
for i in $dir_name; do zip -r $i $i; done
```

Comment: Thsi answer is exactly what I was planning to propose, maybe in a little different form. However, you should make it more robust. If directory names have spaces, this will not work.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot that there are directories with a space!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use bash to do that? If you did, you can use :
`zip -r /root/folder1.zip /root/folder1/; zip -r /root/folder2.zip /root/folder2/`.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a command that exactly finds all your folders. Amend with statements to filter out unwanted directories (like `__pycache__`)

```
ROOT_DIR="./Root"
(olddir=$PWD; cd "$ROOT_DIR"; for foldername in $(ls -1); do [ -d "$foldername" ] && echo "$foldername"; done; cd $olddir)
```

then replace the "echo" statement with your favorite archive command (zip, tar, etc.)
Remember to double-quote variables to support spaces in directory names.

The advantage of the above is that you get "clean" folder names with `./` prefix, so you can use them as the archive name.